# Firefox bug with outline-offset or?

Tags: css, firefox, mozilla

When you hover over a box you will see how left side outline snaps with some delay while other 3 sides snaps in same time smoothly. What do you think guys is it worth filing a bug ?
I am on Win7 machine and I tested in latest stable FF. Do you see that also ?

**DEMO**

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/jovapa/1/edit?css,output)

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 20px solid green;
  outline: navy solid 20px;
  margin: 100px;

  background-color: red;
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/50/50);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-position: center;

  border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-outline-radius:40px;
  outline-offset: 20px;

  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}
#box:hover {
  outline-offset: 0;
}
```

Comment: You should include relevant code *in the question itself*.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Win 7 using Firefox 33.

Comment: weird, I see it but it's barely noticeable.

Comment: Tested with Firefox 33.0.1 (newest release) too, same result.